# perl HTTP::GHTTP set outgoing ip

Tags: perl, http, ip

I would like to dynamically set the outgoing IP of my [HTTP::GHTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/HTTP-GHTTP-1.07/GHTTP.pm) object, however I can find this anywhere in the documentation. Is anyone aware of a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You mean like using the URI `http://127.0.0.1:80/`? That would be no feature of a library, that is a feature of the http protocol.

Comment: No, I mean like my box has multiple IPs on it, and I'd like to be able to specify which IP to identify myself with when I make a request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [libghttp source](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/sources/libghttp/1.0/libghttp-1.0.9.tar.gz), I can't find any mention of anything like a local address.  It's using the normal C socket libraries, so perhaps you can wedge something in using that.

HTTP::GHTTP and libghttp haven't been maintained in 10 years.  The libghttp docs are all but non-existent.  Unless you have a pressing need to use that specific http library I would suggest looking at a maintained option.

[LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) and [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aTiny) are the normal HTTP libraries used in Perl.  [LWP::UserAgent has a local_address property](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#CONSTRUCTOR-METHODS) as does [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aTiny#new).

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to look into using HTTP::GHTTP since I saw it benchmarked faster than LWP::UserAgent, but I guess if you're using Perl that's just the module to use :) Thanks!

Comment: @srchulo If raw speed is what you want [Net::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-HTTP), [HTTP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/release/HTTP-Lite), [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/release/HTTP-Tiny) and [Nginx::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/release/Nginx-HTTP) might perform better. Of course, you have [profiled your application](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::NYTProf) before you started micro-optimizing your HTTP library.